# How can I make page header region full width in Drupal bootstar theme?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drupal-7

I am using the Bootstrap 3 theme. How can I make the page-header full width.  Similar full-width region you can see on [this site](https://github.com/jedireza/drywall).

**HTML code:**
starting from `<header` in the following code

```
<div class="main-container container">
  <header role="banner" id="page-header">   
      <div class="region region-header">
```

**Corresponding page.tpl.php**

```
<div class="main-container <?php print $container_class; ?>">

  <header role="banner" id="page-header" >
    <?php if (!empty($site_slogan)): ?>
      <p class="lead"><?php print $site_slogan; ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php print render($page['header']); ?>
  </header> <!-- /#page-header -->
```

**theme.info file**

```
regions[navigation]     = 'Navigation'
regions[header]         = 'Top Bar' //THIS is correspond to that region
regions[highlighted]    = 'Highlighted'
regions[help]           = 'Help'
regions[content]        = 'Content'
regions[sidebar_first]  = 'Primary'
regions[sidebar_second] = 'Secondary'
regions[footer]         = 'Footer'
regions[page_top]       = 'Page top'
regions[page_bottom]    = 'Page bottom'
```

I tried adding "container-fluid" class in the page.tpl.php file at this code  `<header class="container-fluid" role="banner" id="page-header">` but it is not changing.

The thing is I do not want entire main-content to be fluid, just that region. YOU CAN JUST SEE THE GitHub PAGE which I have linked above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change all the `container` classes inside the navbar to `container-fluid`There is one right agter `navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top`

Comment: I think it is not 'nav-bar'. for nav-bar I did, this is another region below to that. if i show you region from `.info` file, it is like this. `regions[navigation]     = 'Navigation',
regions[header]         = 'Top Bar'`. This region is `Top Bar`.

Comment: This <header> is in main-container. The nv-bar <header> is different

Comment: Post a codepen or jsfiddle hard for me to do anything without seeing your code

Comment: But essentially just rename all `container` to `container-fluid` and youll eventually figure it out

Comment: have just updated, sorry for short info, it was too less, please see the GitHub link to see what I want.